# How to detect and extract the page number in a url?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
url = "https://portal.mvp.bafin.de/database/DealingsInfo/sucheForm.do?meldepflichtigerName=&zeitraum=0&emittentName=&d-5010980-p=189&zeitraumVon=&emittentIsin=&meldepflichtigerButton=Suche+Meldepflichtiger&zeitraumBis="
```

I need help to extract the page number from this url which is `p=189`.

Comment: `from urllib.parse import urlparse` and `dict(f.split('=') for f in urlparse(url).query.split("&"))['d-5010980-p']`

Comment: thank you it works well. but it failed when i try to scrape this a href, any suggestion please <a href="sucheForm.do?meldepflichtigerName=&amp;zeitraum=0&amp;emittentName=&amp;d-5010980-p=189&amp;zeitraumVon=&amp;emittentIsin=&amp;meldepflichtigerButton=Suche+Meldepflichtiger&amp;zeitraumBis=">Ende</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

url = "https://portal.mvp.bafin.de/database/DealingsInfo/sucheForm.do?meldepflichtigerName=&zeitraum=0&emittentName=&d-5010980-p=189&zeitraumVon=&emittentIsin=&meldepflichtigerButton=Suche+Meldepflichtiger&zeitraumBis=" 

print (re.split(r"(p=[0-9]+)&",url)[1])
```

Output:

```
p=189
```

You can use a simple regex split and catch the page number this way.

Comment: thank you sir, can you help me in this similar question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66364738/how-to-detect-and-extract-the-page-number-in-a-scraped-url

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^https://portal\.mvp\.bafin\.de/database/DealingsInfo/sucheForm\.do\?(?:\w|/|=|\&|\+|-)*(?:-p=(\d+)&)(?:\w|/|=|\&|\+|-)*$')

m = regex.match(url)

page = m.groups()[0] if m is not None else None
```

In the case of `url` in the question, `page` will be the string `'189'`.

I assumed that the beginning of the URLs of your interest will be always the same, i.e., `'https://portal.mvp.bafin.de/database/DealingsInfo/sucheForm.do?'`; if it is not the case, you can change it in `regex`.

Answer (score -1):

The magic is in the urllib module:

```
In [265]: from urllib.parse import urlparse                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [266]: urlparse(url)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[266]: ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='portal.mvp.bafin.de', path='/database/DealingsInfo/sucheForm.do', params='', query='meldepflichtigerName=&zeitraum=0&emittentName=&d-5010980-p=189&zeitraumVon=&emittentIsin=&meldepflichtigerButton=Suche+Meldepflichtiger&zeitraumBis=', fragment='')

In [267]: urlparse(url).query                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[267]: 'meldepflichtigerName=&zeitraum=0&emittentName=&d-5010980-p=189&zeitraumVon=&emittentIsin=&meldepflichtigerButton=Suche+Meldepflichtiger&zeitraumBis='

In [268]: urlparse(url).query.split("&")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[268]: 
['meldepflichtigerName=',
 'zeitraum=0',
 'emittentName=',
 'd-5010980-p=189',
 'zeitraumVon=',
 'emittentIsin=',
 'meldepflichtigerButton=Suche+Meldepflichtiger',
 'zeitraumBis=']

In [269]: dict(f.split('=') for f in urlparse(url).query.split("&"))                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[269]: 
{'meldepflichtigerName': '',
 'zeitraum': '0',
 'emittentName': '',
 'd-5010980-p': '189',
 'zeitraumVon': '',
 'emittentIsin': '',
 'meldepflichtigerButton': 'Suche+Meldepflichtiger',
 'zeitraumBis': ''}

In [270]: dict(f.split('=') for f in urlparse(url).query.split("&"))['d-5010980-p']                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[270]: '189'
```

Comment: dict(f.split('=') for f in urlparse(url).query.split("&"))['d-5010980-p']
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)

dict(f.split('=') for f in urlparse(url).query.split("&"))['d-5010980-p']

KeyError: 'd-5010980-p'

Comment: i tried your solution step by step but doesn't work with me and the error occured in the last step