# How to detect and extract the page number in a scraped url?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape a web page which contain a pagination number, i get the url of the last page but i need help for extract the page number from the scraped  which is `p=189`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re  
url = "https://portal.mvp.bafin.de/database/DealingsInfo/sucheForm.do?meldepflichtigerName=&zeitraum=0&emittentName=&d-5010980-p=1&zeitraumVon=&emittentIsin=&meldepflichtigerButton=Suche+Meldepflichtiger&zeitraumBis=" 

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("div", {"class":"displaytag"})
fieldset = table.find("fieldset", {"class":"displaytag"})
span = fieldset.find("span", {"class":"pagelinks"})
url = span.find_all("a")[8]
print(url)
```

The output is HTML `<a href> a href="sucheForm.do?meldepflichtigerName=&amp;zeitraum=0&amp;emittentName=&amp;d-5010980-p=189&amp;zeitraumVon=&amp;emittentIsin=&amp;meldepflichtigerButton=Suche+Meldepflichtiger&amp;zeitraumBis=">Ende</a>`

Comment: it seems to be in the url too, wouldnt it be less effort to use it?

Comment: my goal is to automaticly know the last page number because is variable. first i scrape the page then the pagination numbers for get the last number. when i run fe above code it gives me the while html <a href>. is there any solution to extract the page number from the <a href>

Comment: yeah i change it but still i don't have solution

Comment: when you get the url from href, you can use urllib.parse() to parse the parameters, then you get a dict with all the parameters and you just filter out `p` value, which is the page number. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python

Comment: also I am not sure if you know, but you can extract links from `a` tags in beautiful soup by doing `url['href']` in your case. It would output `sucheForm.do?meldepflichtigerName=&zeitraum=0&emittentName=&d-5010980-p=189&zeitraumVon=&emittentIsin=&meldepflichtigerButton=Suche+Meldepflichtiger&zeitraumBis=` as a string without the whole html tag.

Comment: thank you sir it works now, i'm so appreciated